# Scrolling, Modal, and Misaligned Headers Using JQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am creating a website where a jQuery Datatable is shown within a modal using data loaded from a database. I have the table correctly loading and displaying everything already. The table is rather large so I am trying to use ScrollX to enable horizontal scrolling.

This is my Javascript call for the datatable:

```
<script> 

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("Review.aspx/GetData") %>',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                //datasource = data;
                $('#example').dataTable({
                    "scrollX": true,
                    "scrolly": true,

                    "aaData": JSON.parse(data.d),
                    "columns": [
                        { "data": "ReviewerName" },
                        { "data": "OrigSecObjID" },
                        { "data": "OrigUserID" },
                        { "data": "OrigUserName" },
                        { "data": "OrigEffCRUD" },
                        { "data": "NewSecObjID" },
                        { "data": "NewUserID" },
                        { "data": "NewUserName" },
                        { "data": "NewEffCRUD" },
                        { "data": "Active" },
                        { "data": "ReasonForChange" },
                        { "data": "HaveAccess" },
                        { "data": "VerifiedBy" },
                        { "data": "VerifiedDate" },
                        { "data": "ActionsTaken" },
                        { "data": "ReviewerEmail" },
                        { "data": "ObjectDescription" },
                        { "data": "recordStatus" },
                    ]

                });

            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        })
    });

    $(document).on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $.fn.dataTable.tables({ visible: true, api: true }).columns.adjust().draw();


    });</script>
```

This is my table in my modal:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Reviewer Name</th>
        <th>OrigSecID</th>
        <th>OrigUserID</th>
        <th>OrigUserName</th>
        <th>OrigEffCRUD</th>
        <th>NewSecObjID</th>
        <th>NewUserID</th>
        <th>NewUserName</th>
        <th>NewEffCRUD</th>
        <th>Active</th>
        <th>ReasonForChange</th>
        <th>HaveAccess</th>
        <th>VerifiedBy</th>
        <th>VerifiedDate</th>
        <th>ActionsTaken</th>
        <th>ReviewerEmail</th>
        <th>ObjectDescription</th>
        <th>recordStatus</th>

     </tr>
</thead></table>
```

I have looked over this site and others and tried many methods to try and get this to work and they all fail. I have tried using a scrollable div instead of the built in scrollx, columns.adjust, etc.

If I remove the scrolling features, the headers align just fine (though the table is cut off because of how large it is).

If I look at the elements tab in the developer console I can see where class dataTables_scrollHead is positioned correctly but dataTables_scrollHeadInner is not.

[Incorrect Alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1nXg.jpg)

[Correct Alignment with No Scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMHJQ.jpg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of troubleshooting etc. I found this worked:

Add to css:

```
div.dataTables_scrollHeadInner { margin-left: 0px !important; margin-right: 10px !important;}
```

Then the last column was getting cut off a bit, so I added a dummy blank column:

```
<script> 

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("Review.aspx/GetData") %>',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                //datasource = data;
                $('#example').dataTable({
                    "scrollX": true,


                    "aaData": JSON.parse(data.d),
                    "columns": [
                        { "data": "ReviewerName" },
                        { "data": "OrigSecObjID" },
                        { "data": "OrigUserID" },
                        { "data": "OrigUserName" },
                        { "data": "OrigEffCRUD" },
                        { "data": "NewSecObjID" },
                        { "data": "NewUserID" },
                        { "data": "NewUserName" },
                        { "data": "NewEffCRUD" },
                        { "data": "Active" },
                        { "data": "ReasonForChange" },
                        { "data": "HaveAccess" },
                        { "data": "VerifiedBy" },
                        { "data": "VerifiedDate" },
                        { "data": "ActionsTaken" },
                        { "data": "ReviewerEmail" },
                        { "data": "ObjectDescription" },
                        { "data": "recordStatus" },
                        { "defaultContent": "" }
                    ]

                }).fnAdjustColumnSizing();

            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        })
    });


    $(document).on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $.fn.dataTable.tables({ visible: true, api: true }).columns.adjust().draw();


    });</script>
```

Table:

```
  <table id="example" class="display" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Reviewer Name</th>
        <th>OrigSecID</th>
        <th>OrigUserID</th>
        <th>OrigUserName</th>
        <th>OrigEffCRUD</th>
        <th>NewSecObjID</th>
        <th>NewUserID</th>
        <th>NewUserName</th>
        <th>NewEffCRUD</th>
        <th>Active</th>
        <th>ReasonForChange</th>
        <th>HaveAccess</th>
        <th>VerifiedBy</th>
        <th>VerifiedDate</th>
        <th>ActionsTaken</th>
        <th>ReviewerEmail</th>
        <th>ObjectDescription</th>
        <th>Status of Record</th>
        <th></th>

     </tr>
</thead>
```

Now works and aligns like a charm!